# Insert own tags to JasperReports jrxml

Tags: jasper-reports

I have MyRenderable class implements Renderable. It returns bytes of special image which created inside of my application (bytes array in methods getImageData)
This looks like

```
 < image scaleImage="RealSize" >   
< reportElement mode="Opaque"  positionType="Float"  x="300" y="100"/> 
< imageExpression>         
< ![ CDATA[ MyImageRenderer("< attributes>" + 
        "< caption-text>IMAGE CAPTION< /caption-text>" +  
   "< color>BLUE</color>" +  
   "< margin-left>11< /margin-left>" + 
   "< margin-right>22< /margin-right>" +   
  "< margin-top>33< /margin-top>" +   
  "< margin-bottom>44< /margin-bottom>" + 
  "< /attributes>")]]>    < / imageExpression>
```

In this code I init new instance MyImageRenderer, passes there parameters for image. In this part of report will be rendered image. I want to avoid using 
`<![ CDATA[MyImageRenderer(...) and write my own tags just inside <imageExpression>`. How can I use my own parser for my tags inside of jrxml?